# Model_Test for Qt 5?

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

In the past (Qt 4.8), I've used the [modeltest](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Model_Test) class to test `QAbstractItemModel` implementations. However, it seems with Qt 5 they've broken compatibility as a slew of errors erupts when trying to compile it out of the box, including calls to functions like `reset()` which are no longer members of `QAbstractItemModel`.

Does anyone know of an updated repository, or has anyone fixed `modeltest` of their own accord? I'm specifically using Qt 5.3.1.

### ERRORS:

```
C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\dynamictreemodel.cpp(306): error C2039: 'reset' : is not a member of 'DynamicTreeModel'
1>          c:\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\modeltest\dynamictreemodel.h(51) : see declaration of 'DynamicTreeModel'
1>  modeltest.cpp
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(419): error C2065: 'qVariantCanConvert' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(419): error C2275: 'QString' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          C:\Qt\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\include\QtCore/qstring.h(213) : see declaration of 'QString'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(423): error C2065: 'qVariantCanConvert' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(423): error C2275: 'QString' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          C:\Qt\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\include\QtCore/qstring.h(213) : see declaration of 'QString'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(427): error C2065: 'qVariantCanConvert' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(427): error C2275: 'QString' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          C:\Qt\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\include\QtCore/qstring.h(213) : see declaration of 'QString'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(433): error C2065: 'qVariantCanConvert' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(433): error C2275: 'QSize' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          C:\Qt\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\include\QtCore/qsize.h(51) : see declaration of 'QSize'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(439): error C2065: 'qVariantCanConvert' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(439): error C2275: 'QFont' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          C:\Qt\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\include\QtGui/qfont.h(58) : see declaration of 'QFont'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(452): error C2065: 'qVariantCanConvert' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(452): error C2275: 'QColor' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          C:\Qt\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\include\QtGui/qcolor.h(65) : see declaration of 'QColor'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(457): error C2065: 'qVariantCanConvert' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\modeltest.cpp(457): error C2275: 'QColor' : illegal use of this type as an expression
1>          C:\Qt\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\qt-5.3.1-x64-msvc2010-opengl\include\QtGui/qcolor.h(65) : see declaration of 'QColor'
1>  tst_modeltest.cpp
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(114): error C2065: 'QTreeWidget' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(114): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'widget'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(114): error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(116): error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(116): error C2228: left of '.model' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'unknown-type'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(116): error C2512: 'ModelTest' : no appropriate default constructor available
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(118): error C2065: 'QTreeWidgetItem' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(118): error C2065: 'root' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(118): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'QTreeWidgetItem'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(120): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'QTreeWidgetItem'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(122): error C2065: 'QTreeWidgetItem' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(122): error C2065: 'root' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(122): error C2227: left of '->child' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>          type is 'unknown-type'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(123): error C2065: 'root' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(123): error C2227: left of '->removeChild' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
1>          type is 'unknown-type'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(124): error C2065: 'QTreeWidgetItem' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(124): error C3867: 'QObject::parent': function call missing argument list; use '&QObject::parent' to create a pointer to member
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(124): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'QTreeWidgetItem'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(126): error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(126): error C2228: left of '.setItemHidden' must have class/struct/union
1>          type is 'unknown-type'
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(126): error C3867: 'QObject::parent': function call missing argument list; use '&QObject::parent' to create a pointer to member
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(128): error C2065: 'widget' : undeclared identifier
1>C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\modeltest\tst_modeltest.cpp(128): error C2228: left of '.sortByColumn' must have class/struct/union
```

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/bruceoutdoors/Intro-Design-Patterns-Cpp-Qt5/tree/master/libs/modeltest Is it help? I used this modeltest a few minutes ago without issue, but I use MinGW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this can be fixed with a few easy steps:

1. The `reset()` error is testing a deprecated function, and can be commented out.
2. The `qVariantCanConvert` errors can be fixed by following the advice [here on transitioning from Qt 4.8 to Qt 5](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5#6fc981baf045630af42b49ef0525ace3)
3. The rest of the errors can be solved by making sure all the appropriate headers are included.